# css - fixed position sidebar navigation overlapping with footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using [bootstrap's affix code](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-affix.js) in my website.

But its overlapping in the footer.

Can someone help me to stop the scroll before footer instead of overlapping it.

I have a created a demo to show you, how my website looks like.

Full page jsfiddle `demo`:

[click here to view it](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/Z6Uzm/1/embedded/result/)

Here is the code.

[click here to view it](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/Z6Uzm/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a plugin which does this job. I hope this answer will be useful to others

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed